# No sees play.db.ebean.*;

Tags: scala, playframework, playframework-2.0

I am a beginner in playframework, and I have a problem with import play.db.ebean.*; because no sees it.

- db.default.driver=org.h2.Driver
- db.default.url="jdbc:h2:mem:play"
- ebean.default="models.*"

I have uncommented lines in file application.conf, but still not working. This is my build.sbt

```
import play.Project._
name := """play2bars-java"""
version := "1.0-SNAPSHOT"

libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  javaJdbc,
  javaEbean,
    "org.webjars" %% "webjars-play" % "2.2.0",
    "org.webjars" % "bootstrap" % "2.3.1")


playJavaSettings
```

Comment: _because no sees it._ Hmmm what exactly do you mean?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It works. I created a project in the console play and work. Previously, I created a project in typesafe activator "[basics] Hello Play Framework (Java Only)" and did not work

Answer (score 0):

Does your `build.sbt` file contain the javaEbean dependancy?

```
libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
    javaJdbc,
    javaEbean,
    "org.webjars" %% "webjars-play" % "2.2.0", 
    "org.webjars" % "bootstrap" % "2.3.1")
```

Comment: Yes, I have javaEbean in the file build.sbt. I do play reload, play compile and is successful, but still can not see play.db.ebean.*;.

Comment: Try adding javaJdbc to the dependencies.

Comment: I suggest you try the play-forms project from the templates. Try to run it and see if you get similar errors.